# Passing UIPicker selection to a firstViewController Tab based app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

So i have a problem thats been a bit of a challenge to figure out on my own, I have an application which has 2 tabs:

First tab (firstViewController) which has a TAP mechanism to execute a certain method in the firstViewController ONLY if it was choosen in the Second Tab (secondViewController).

In SecondViewController i have a UIPickerView with 3 data selections. in this code i exclude the NSArray holding the data but include a method i use to display that data on the same "secondViewController" to show the user in a UILable object what is being picked.

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{


 NSString *displayPickerInString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",coffeeSize[row]];
  self.displayPickerData.text = displayPickerInString;

FirstViewController *firstvs = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];

NSInteger selectedRow = [self.pickerView selectedRowInComponent: 0];

if (selectedRow == 0) {
    NSLog(@"Invalid Row"); // This block will not do nothing
}
else if (selectedRow == 1) {

    // Call a method in firstViewController
    firstvs.smallSelection;

}
else if (selectedRow == 2) {
    // Call a methos in firstViewController
    firstvs.mediumSelection;
}
else if (selectedRow == 3){
    // Call a method in firstViewController
    firstvs.largeSelection;
}
```

}

So this method works and displays it Locally in the same secondViewController, The PROBLEM is i want to execute that selection on firstViewController with a tap according to the selection.

Say i chose Row 1, to execute a method in this code:

```
    firstvs.smallSelection;
```

In firstViewController i have that method as follows:

```
   -(void) smallSelection {
    NSLog(@"Small selection has been chosen");
    }
```

In the debug window i see it works, but only executes in the firstViewController if i call this method on the tab method:

```
   -(void) selection {
     [self smallSelection];
     }
```

this does execute the method but iwant it conditionally, here is the full code and in pheseudo code of what i am trying to explain in regular plain english:

```
    - (void) tapScreen:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gr
     {

      [self refresh:self]; // call the refresh method as the screen is tapped

      NSLog(@"Screen has been tapped");

      timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1 target: self selector: @selector(selection) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];

  }

 -(void) selection { 


// I want to call these according to selection made on secondViewController

// so in Phseudo code, i want it like so:

if selectionFromPicker was row1

{
[self smallSelection];

}
else if selectionFromPicker was row2
{
    [self mediumSelection];
}
else if selectionFromPicker was row3
{
    [self largeSelection];
   }
 }
```

To wrap things up, the user selects an option choice in secondViewController from the UIPicker, and that selection is passed to firstViewController and the user taps the screen to execute the selection made and the tap recognizes the selection with Conditional
statements and does what it is intended for that use, say the user goes back to the picker
and selects a different row and taps the screen, that selection is executed on the firstViewController. Any help ? feel free to ask more question if i am not being clear.

Comment: NSNotificationCenter? If I understand your question correctly, that should work.

Comment: I am trying to avoid that since i am not familiar how it works yet, i barely even know how to use it

Answer (score 0):

NSNotificationCenter is pretty simple to use. In your first VC, you can put in this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                      selector:@selector(notificationReceived:)
                                      name:@"notificationName" object:nil];
```

This will basically add the VC as an observer, meaning it will constantly watch for the notification. once the notification is received, it will perform the selector you put in `selector:`.

Now in the second VC, which is were you want to post the notification you will add:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notificationName"
                                      object:self];
```

The only other thing that I will note to watch for is adding observers. If you put the `NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:` in a method that is repeated, then it will add another observer every time it gets called. For example, if you put it in the `viewDidLoad` method, you will add an observer every time the view loads and that will cause the selector to be called multiple times. to handle this, you need to call `removeObserver` so that it will not continuously create new observers for the same notification.

And for some more info on NSNotificationCenter: [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [Tutorial](http://www.devfright.com/nsnotificationcenter-tutorial/).

Comment: I dont know if the first method goes in the secondViewcontroller as it implies it must go and the second NSNotificationCenter sounds like it must go in the firstVC since it says postNotificationName: @"NotificationName" since on top of my head it seems to do the method selection when a choice is made from the secondViewController. i tried this method by putthing the 2 NSNotificationcenters in each viewcontrollers ViewDidLoad and nothing seemed to happen